# GetDiskFreeSpaceEx fails despite enabled SeBackupPrivilege

Tags: windows, winapi, acl, privileges, elevated-privileges

I created a directory to which no one (even the owner) has access: empty DACL + disabled inheritance.
When calling `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` on the directory, I get `Access is denied` despite enabling SeBackupPrivilege.

Here is my script:

```
import win32api
import win32security
import os
import sys


def enable_privilege(priv):
    token_handle = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
        win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    )
    state_change = []
    luid = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    state_change.append((luid, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED))
    adjusted_privileges = win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(token_handle, 0, state_change)
    is_priv_set = len(adjusted_privileges) == len(state_change)
    if not is_priv_set:
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to set privilege")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]
    enable_privilege(win32security.SE_BACKUP_NAME)
    print(os.listdir(path))
    print(os.stat(path))
    print(win32api.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path))
```

Output:

```
> python C:\tmp\script.py C:\tmp\no-access

['file.txt']
os.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=4222124652180108, st_dev=2523844702, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0, st_atime=1653639492, st_mtime=1653559396, st_ctime=1653559388)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tmp\script.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(win32api.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path))
pywintypes.error: (5, 'GetDiskSpaceFreeEx', 'Access is denied.')
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskfreespaceexw FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY permission is necessary to call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`. SeBackupPrivilege should cover the permission.

Why is that? It's Windows 10.

Comment: SeBackupPrivilege should cover the permission only in case you use `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` option when open file. `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` not use it

Answer (score -1):

According to [Null DACLs and Empty DACLs (Authorization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/null-dacls-and-empty-dacls),

> An empty DACL is a properly allocated and initialized DACL that
> contains no access control entries (ACEs). **An empty DACL grants no
> access to the object it is assigned to.**

So Access is denied.